# Use of included class in another class

Tags: php, oop, adodb

I'm trying to use a database class (ADOdb for PHP) but I don't know how to use it in another class.
Example:

```
<?php
include_once("adodb.inc.php");
$conn = NewADOConnection('mysql');

class Contacts {
    public function getData(){
        $conn->Connect(...);
        //do something
    }
}
?>
```

I think the problem is that I can not call $conn because its defined outside the class.

**Notice: Undefined variable: conn**

**Fatal error: Call to a member function Connect() on a non-object**

Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way, but I really don't know how to fix this.

Can somebody please help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should ready more about variable scopes in PHP < http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply do like this ?!

```
<?php
include_once("adodb.inc.php");
$conn = NewADOConnection('mysql');

$conn->Connect(...);

class Contacts {

    protected $_connection;

    public function __construct($conn)
    {
        $this->_connection = $conn;
    }
    public function getData(){

        //do something

    }
}

$contacts = new Contacts($conn);

$foobar = new FooBar($conn);

?>
```

It makes sense to establish connection outside the class, and then pass in already workable object. And of-course to share the same connection object among all the classes which require it.

P.S i would really **reallly** recommend to drop ADODB and start learning [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: Doesn't my connection stays open all the time when I establish it above the class? I don't really like that or doesn't that matter?

Comment: Yes, it stays open, but the Contacts class should not be responsible for establishing connection or know the connection details. And it makes error handling somewhat more convoluted. And what about the next class which would use it .. you would have to check if connection is already open .. and what if you change the order in which you use the classes .. as i said - its a mess.

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks. I was using ADODB for not making my database connection over and over again. But I really don't know what's the best way to "make" connection when I'm (trying hehe) to code OOP.

Answer (score 4):

You have a number of choices:

Use the global reserve word:

```
<?php
include_once("adodb.inc.php");
$conn = NewADOConnection('mysql');

class Contacts {
    public function getData(){
        global $conn;
        $conn->Connect(...);
        //do something
    }
}
?>
```

Or pass $conn to your object on creation

```
$contacts = new Contacts($conn);

class Contacts {
    protected $conn;
    public function __construct($conn){
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
    public function getData(){
        $this->conn->Connect(...);
        //do something
    }
}
?>
```

Or you could yous a Singleton data connection object. But that is considered a anti-pattern so I would inject your dependency as in option 2.

Answer (score 2):

you need to reference the global variable:

```
<?php
include_once("adodb.inc.php");
$conn = NewADOConnection('mysql');

class Contacts {
    public function getData(){
        global $conn;
        $conn->Connect(...);
        //do something
    }
}
?>
```

That said, you would probably be better off using dependency injection like this:

```
<?php
class Contacts {

    private $db;

    public function setDB($conn) {
        $this->db = $conn;
    }

    public function getData(){
        if (!$this->db) { 
            throw new Exception();
        }
        $conn = $this->db;
        $conn->Connect(...);
        //do something
    }
}
?>
```

And then include your adodb include and instantiation in an initialization section.

Edit: Please see this article on [Dependency Injection](http://www.potstuck.com/2009/01/08/php-dependency-injection/) as getting into the habit of using this (and not globals) may save a lot of headaches down the road.

Comment: Woulda +1'd you but the connection is so vital it should come in on the contructor like Tim Cooper,PabloSerbo

Answer (score 1):

`$conn` is out of your variable scope. Use the following to make it work:

```
class Contacts {
    public function getData(){
        global $conn;
        $conn->Connect(...);
        //do something
    }
}
```

Another way to do it is to have a reference to the variable inside your object:

```
class Contacts {
    private $ref;
    public function __construct($conn)
    {
        $this->ref = $conn;
    }
    public function getData(){
        $ref->Connect(...);
        //do something
    }
}

$contacts = new Contacts($conn);
```

Comment: I was trying to make a GLOBAL var but I did it the wrong way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible to define the GLOBAL var somewhere else inside the CLASS, so I don't have to define them all over again in other functions?

Comment: using global never a solutions